# Сниппет не копируется в самоответ

Tags: предложение, сниппеты, самоответы

Задаю [вопрос со сниппетом](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708781/178988) и отмечаю флажок

> Ответить на собственный вопрос – делитесь знаниями в стиле вопросов и ответов

После этого хочу скопировать код сниппета в ответ, что обычно делается кнопкой <kbd>Копировать код в ответ</kbd>:

> [image: скриншот с кнопкой]

Однако, в форме вопроса с ответом этой кнопки нет:

> [image: скриншот без кнопки]

Предлагаю добавить.

Comment: А так же при правке вопроса/ответа со сниппетом.

Comment: Ну при правке-то можно сначала закончить правку. А вот тут смысл флажка в том, что вопрос и ответ постятся одновременно. А кнопки нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а почему вы не можете там выделить и туда вставить?

Comment: @Yuri, я могу. Но в случае длинных сниппетов или нескольких сниппетов кнопка намного удобнее, посколько копирует только нужный кусок.

Comment: @Qwertiy, было бы